# Parallel tesseract ocr on Android

Tags: android, parallel-processing, ocr, tesseract

Is it possible to parallelize Tesseract OCR Process in order to speed up on Android? For example the basic process in all procedure is baseApi.getUTF8Text(); Can this be parallelized? and how?

I have found this: 
Tesseract release notes Oct 21 2011 - V3.01 =
 * Thread-safety! Moved all critical globals and statics to members of the appropriate class. Tesseract is now thread-safe (multiple instances can be used in parallel in multiple threads.) with the minor exception that some control parameters are still global and affect all threads.

but how can i make use of it?